# jQuery datepicker validation message issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jquery datepicker plugin at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/datepick with the datepicker validation plugin.

```
<script id="frmValidation" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var validator = $("#frmTest").validate({
        rules:{
            fname: "required",
            dobPicker: "required" 
        },
        messages:{
            fname: "Please enter a name",
            dobPicker: "Select a date"
        },

    });
    $('#dobPicker').datepick();
    $.datepick.setDefaults({showOn: 'both', dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', yearRange:'1900:2010'});
});
</script>
```

And the body of the document is as follows :

```
<form id="frmTest" action="" method="post">
<div id="error-list"></div>
<div class="form-row">
<span class="label"><label for="fname">Name</label></span>
<input type="text" name="fname" />
</div>
<div class="form-row">
<span class="label"><label for="dobPicker">DOB</label></span>
<input type="text" id="dobPicker" name="dobPicker" style="margin-left: 4px;"/>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>
</form>
```

The form validates the first time but the error message for the datepicker does not disappear immediately a date is selected.. however it goes away if the date is selected the second time.  Any help to make it go the first time a date is selected will be appreciated

Comment: I feel it is something to do with the events that the datepicker generates, the validation plugin validates only on certain events..

Comment: See this for more info: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/issues/70

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want to set this in your datepicker defaults:

```
onClose: function() {$(this).valid();},
```

As soon as another date is selected it will make the validator plugin recheck the field.

Comment: You may actually want to do `onSelect: function() { $(this).valid(); }`, otherwise, if you don't want validation to fire until the form is submitted, if the person opens the datapicker (by setting focus to the field) the validation error message will fire when they set focus to another field. If you put it onSelect, it will mark the field valid when they actually select a value.

Answer (score 3):

The "best answer" didn't work for me.  I figured out that the validator was validating the date format even though I didn't ask it to.  Here's my solution:

```
$('form').validate(
    rules:
    {
        MyDateControl:{
            required:true,
            date:false
        }
    }
);
```