# datepicker validation

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker

I have two inputs fields of date:

```
<input type='text' id='txtLeaveDate' name='txtLeaveDate' class='date'  /> 
<input type='text' id='txtArriveDate' name='txtArriveDate' class='date' />
```

validation script:

```
$().ready(function() {
// validate the comment form when it is submitted

// validate signup form on keyup and submit
$('#ticketform').validate({
    rules: {
        txtLeaveDate: 'required',
                    txtArriveDate: 'required'

    },
    messages: {
        txtLeaveDate: 'Required!',
        txtArriveDate: 'Required!'

    }
});
});
</script>
```

and datepicker script:

```
    $('.date').datepicker({
        dateFormat:'dd.mm.yy',
        onClose: function () {
            $('.date').valid();
        }

    });
```

But always I have error messages: 'Required'.

Additionaly, I want to do that  #txtArriveDate mustn't be earlier than #txtLeaveDate, but I don't know is it possible.

Comment: For the second part. Compare the the two dates and return false if the first is greater than second in ticketForm validation

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287011/jquery-datepicker-validation-message-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because my input had `class='date`', it was validated and was wrong. I had one message Required! for all of the problems. That was reason.

To second part I uset this tutorial: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/01/end-date-should-not-be-greater-than.html

Answer (score 1):

have a look on this [jQuery Datepicker validation](http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html) There are so many types of validation avaialble in this file. Do as you want

Answer (score -1):

Please check your jquery jar, It may be due conflict ion between the jar.
Because same problem i have faced and found the conflict ion between the jquery jars.