# JQuery datepicker erratic client side validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, datepicker

I'm using MVC 4 with strong typed view and in my form I have a date field, using jquery datepicker...

I will show you with a sumarized example:

Using the following in the displayed order...

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

The view...

```
<div class="control-group">  
    @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.CAAD_Fecha_Contacto, new { @class = "control-label" })      
    <div class="controls">  
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.CAAD_Fecha_Contacto, new { @class = "datepicker", autocomplete = "off" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The Model...

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "La fecha de contacto es obligatoria")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")]
[DisplayName("Fecha de contacto con notificador")]
public System.DateTime? CAAD_Fecha_Contacto { get; set; }
```

Client side validation code:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", weekStart: 1, autoclose: true });


$('#casoAdversoForm').validate(
{
    rules: {
        CAAD_Fecha_Contacto: {
            required: true,
            },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function (element) {
        element.closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    }
});
```

The datepicker is displayed fine and when I select a date, the input-validation-error will be removed and the valid class will be placed. At least this is the expected behaviour.

But in my case it happens that the input-validation-class won't be removed until I click and select again the date, maybe 4, 5 or 6 times. After that the valid class appears...

I thought it was something related to the dateformat (dd/mm/yy), but it isn't. If I put 12/12/2012, valid for both EU or US format, it still shows error.

The errors that appears are also erratic. Sometimes it appear that the field is required (being the field not empty) or it warns about the date format...

The only way that it is possible to make it work is by removing the datepicker initialization $('.datepicker').datepicker();

If I write the date manually it appears to work.

Comment: why are you using 2 different validation scripts? What happens if you remove the unobtrusive one?

Comment: I've removed the script, but the issue still remains. It's strange that when removing the datepicker initialization it appears to work fine when typing the date manually... It's like some sort of conflict exists with the datepicker script

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery datepicker validation message issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287011/jquery-datepicker-validation-message-issue)

Comment: Ryley, thank you. Yes, you were right, the proposed solution in that question has worked for me too. The erratic behaviour that I've told appears to be dissapeared after several tests. If you put that as the question, I'll mark it as correct.