# JQuery Bootstrap datepicker validation error not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, datepicker

I've been banging my head against this error for days (on & off) now and now need another pair of eyes to tell me where I'm going wrong. I think it's something simple but can't see it.

The problem I'm having is the validation message doesn't show on the date picker field.

The code below WORKS because the validation shows on the field below the `datepicker` field.  The trouble is this field should be hidden, and if I hide it the error message doesn't show.

If I change the jQuery validation to work on the `datepicker` field it the error message won't show.

I thought the code found on this page would help so I've included the file and added the `dpDate: true` as the page suggests but still no joy.:

http://keith-wood.name/uidatepickervalidation.html

I hope this makes sense and someone can help me.

Here's my HTML / jQuery

This works for `startDate3` but not if renamed for the datepicker field `startDate2`:

```js
$("#editEventForm").validate ({
rules: {
 artwork: { filesize: 2097152  },
 name:  {
  required: true,
  minlength: 2,
  maxlength: 50
 },
 desc: {
  required: true,
  minlength: 2,
  maxlength: 3000
 },
 venue2: {
  required: true
 },
 startDate3: {
  required: true, 
  dpDate: true 
 },
 endDate3: {
  required: true
 },
 showFrom3: {
  required: true,
  greaterThan: "#startDate3"
 },
 cutOffDate3: {
  required: true
 },
 totalSubCat: {
  minStrict: 0,
  maxStrict: 4
 }
},
messages: {
 name: "Please enter your name longer than 2 and less than 50 characters",
 desc: "Please enter a description longer than 2 and less than 3000 characters",
 venue2: "Please choose a venue",
 startDate3: "Please enter a start date/time",
 endDate3: "Please enter an end date/time",
 showFrom3: "Please enter a show from date",
 cutOffDate3: "Please enter a cut off date",
 totalSubCat: "Please choose between 1 and 3 categories"
}
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<i class="fa fa-question" id="startDate"></i>
<label for="startDate2">Start</label>
<div class="input-group date form_datetime" data-date="<?= date( 'Y-m-d' ) ?>T19:00:00Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="startDate3">
 <input class="form-control" name="startDate2" id="startDate2" required size="16" type="text" readonly>
 <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
 <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
</div>
<input type="" id="startDate3" name="startDate3" /><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: You missed to add jquery in your snipped.

Comment: Are you using just html?

Comment: I'm using jquery & html (made with php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed some libraries, not only jquery:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#editEventForm").validate (
    {
      rules: {
        artwork: { filesize: 2097152  },
        name:  {
          required: true,
          minlength: 2,
          maxlength: 50
        },
        desc: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 2,
          maxlength: 3000
        },
        venue2: {
          required: true
        },
        validDefaultDatepicker: {
          required: true,
          dpDate: true
        },
        startDate3: {
          required: true,
          dpDate: true
        },
        endDate3: {
          required: true
        },
        showFrom3: {
          required: true,
          greaterThan: "#startDate3"
        },
        cutOffDate3: {
          required: true
        },
        totalSubCat: {
          minStrict: 0,
          maxStrict: 4
        }
      },
      messages: {
        name: "Please enter your name longer than 2 and less than 50 characters",
        desc: "Please enter a description longer than 2 and less than 3000 characters",
        venue2: "Please choose a venue",
        startDate3: "Please enter a start date/time",
        endDate3: "Please enter an end date/time",
        showFrom3: "Please enter a show from date",
        cutOffDate3: "Please enter a cut off date",
        totalSubCat: "Please choose between 1 and 3 categories"
      }
    }
  );
  $('#startDate2').datepicker();
  $('#startDate3').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<form id="editEventForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <i class="fa fa-question" id="startDate"></i>
        <label for="startDate2">Start</label>
        <div class="input-group date form_datetime" data-date="<?= date( 'Y-m-d' ) ?>T19:00:00Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="startDate3">
            <input class="form-control" name="startDate2" id="startDate2" required size="16" type="text" >
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
        </div>
        <input type="" id="startDate3" name="startDate3" /><br/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="ClickMe">
</form>
```

Comment: I've included these libraries:


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
 <script src="/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
 <script src="/includes/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src='//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
 <script src="/dist/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script src="/dist/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.js"></script>

Comment: @GeneralTomfoolery Like you see it works in the snippet. You may copy or see the differences with your code. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @gaemaf, I've played spot the difference in my code & yours and have won. Only weird thing is the 'glyphicon' for the datepicker stretches when the error shows, I don't suppose ou have the cure for that please? Thanks again.

Comment: Also (sorry for bugging you), only the first form control filed works.  In this case it is startDate3 but there are others after it which the validation does not work.  If I delete startDate, the next field in the form begins to work - like it can only do this once - weird huh?

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the following attributes to your input element which allows you to add your own validation messages. You can place whatever message you like in between the " ".

```
data-rule-required="true" data_val_date = "Please enter a valid date"
```

Comment: I really want it to work via the jquery.validation rules

Comment: have you checked out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287011/jquery-datepicker-validation-message-issue

Comment: Hi Scanner - your suggestion for data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Error!!!!" didn't show anything.  Is that normal?

Comment: @GeneralTomfoolery, sorry I had pulled that from a previous project of mine, for date error message it constructed as above, see my update answer. I don't think for date that you need data-rule-required="true", but you can try it with and without and see which works