# jQuery validator datepicker get rid of error message when right date is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

My validation would be if the user is 18 years old or above. My first attempt is selecting the right age and then on the second attempt it will be on the wrong age in the date picker and then on the third attempt it would be in the right age. It prompts correctly on the second attempt but on the third, the error message remains. I just wanted to get rid of the message when the user is above 18 years old. Tried all solutions here on this website but unfortunately does not work on my case. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth" placeholder="Date of Birth">
```

jQuery

```
 // Datepicker
$('#dateofbirth').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '-100:-0'
)};

// jQuery Validation
$.validator.addMethod("birthdate", function(value, element) {
    var date = $('#dateofbirth').datepicker('getDate'),
        day  = date.getDate(),
        month = date.getMonth() + 1,
        year =  date.getFullYear();

    var mydate = new Date();
    mydate.setFullYear(year, month - 1, day);

    var currdate = new Date();
    currdate.setFullYear(currdate.getFullYear() - 18);

    return currdate > mydate;
}, "You are not at the right age");

// Form Rules
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        required: true,
        date: true,
        birthdate: true
   },
   messages: {
        dateofbirth: {
            required: 'Please enter your birth date using the date picker'
        }
   }
});
```

Tried this [jQuery datepicker validation message issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287011/jquery-datepicker-validation-message-issue) but it does not work on my case. Can someone please help me.

Comment: I don't know if your code for your actual case differs, but you have a parentheses-curly brace imbalance on your functions. For example "validate({" ends with ")};"

Comment: @Adam thank you sir for replying. I edited it sorry for typo.