# JQUERY Datepicker - validation error doesn't go away after selecting a date from datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker and it seems there are some issues with validation error. After validation error if i select a date from datepicker then validation message doesn't go away. It disappears if i select the date second time.

Here are the steps to reproduce this;

1- Type in wrong date format.
2- Invalid date format error will be shown.
3- Now select a date from the datepicker.
4- Error message showon in steps two is still there.

I have done some research on this and have tried the solution given on this link with no luck.

[jQuery datepicker validation message issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287011/jquery-datepicker-validation-message-issue)

Here is my code;

```js
$("#date").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});

$('form').validate({
  rules: {
    date: {
      required: true,
      dateISO: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    date: {
      required: "Date required",
      dateISO: "Invalid date. Must be formatted dd/mm/yy"
    }
  }
});


$.validator.addMethod('date',
  function(value, element) {

    if (this.optional(element)) {
      return true;
    }

    var ok = true;
    try {
      $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
    } catch (err) {
      ok = false;
    }
    return ok;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
  <input id="date" name="date" />
</form>
```

Comment: what is the point of creating a snippet if it isn't working

Comment: don't know why its not working in chrome, works fine in IE and firefox. I actually posted a link to my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m7wMe/16/ but i think admin changed that to snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Observations

- The reason your error message is being shown after the first time it's due to the empty initialization of input `date`.

Look this code snippet, the input is initialized with a dateISO *(Later we are going to talk about it)*.

```js
$("#date").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});

$('form').validate({
  rules: {
    date: {
      required: true,
      dateISO: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    date: {
      required: "Date required",
      dateISO: "Invalid date. Must be formatted dd/mm/yy"
    }
  }
});


$.validator.addMethod('date',
  function(value, element) {

    if (this.optional(element)) {
      return true;
    }

    var ok = true;
    try {
      $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
    } catch (err) {
      ok = false;
    }
    console.log(ok)
    return ok;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
  <input id="date" name="date" value='2018-01-02' />
</form>
```

See, now the input `date` was initialized.

Great, but why the message error still appears?  The reason is the flag `dateISO: true`.  The validator is expecting this format: `yy-mm-dd`.

**Look this code snippet without that flag:**

```js
$("#date").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});

$('form').validate({
  rules: {
    date: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    date: {
      required: "Date required",
      dateISO: "Invalid date. Must be formatted dd/mm/yy"
    }
  }
});


$.validator.addMethod('date',
  function(value, element) {

    if (this.optional(element)) {
      return true;
    }

    var ok = true;
    try {
      $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
    } catch (err) {
      ok = false;
    }
    console.log(ok)
    return ok;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
  <input id="date" name="date" value='2018-01-02' />
</form>
```

See, now the error message is not appearing.

You need to decide what's the format you're going to use.  For example, if we change the format to `dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'` with flag `dateISO: true` everything works perfect.

**Run the following code snippet:**

```js
$("#date").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});

$('form').validate({
  rules: {
    date: {
      required: true,
      dateISO: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    date: {
      required: "Date required",
      dateISO: "Invalid date. Must be formatted yy-mm-dd"
    }
  }
});


$.validator.addMethod('date',
  function(value, element) {

    if (this.optional(element)) {
      return true;
    }

    var ok = true;
    try {
      $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', value);
    } catch (err) {
      ok = false;
    }
    console.log(ok)
    return ok;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
  <input id="date" name="date" value='2018-01-02' />
</form>
```

See, it works.

Decide what's the format you really need and set the right flags.

Comment: Error suppose to be displaed when user type in wrong date format.Your snippet doesn't show any error and accepting 2018-21-21 . As far as date format is concerned, I will be using dd/mm/yy dateformat.